# Getting a null pointer exception on a number picker - Android

Tags: android, timer, numberpicker

I am trying to do a simple "number picker" function that was custom made (**not** using the NumberPicker widget), by aligning 3 of them side by side. I got one to work just fine, but as soon as I added the other 2, then tried to change variable names (and adjusted it in the `MainActivity`), the program crashed with a `NullPointer Exception`. It is saying `line 29` is the culprit (`caused by`) in the `MainActivity`.

I probably don't understand the MainActivity code very well, as it was code I borrowed. Why is it crashing? Thanks.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.azurespot.numbpicksample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnUp, btnDown;
    TextView textViewUp, textViewMid, textViewBottom;

    int nStart = 0;
    int nEnd = 59;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp1|R.id.buttonUp2|R.id.buttonUp3);
        btnDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDown1|R.id.buttonDown2|R.id.buttonDown3);

        // All the numbers
        textViewUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plus1|R.id.plus2|R.id.plus3);
        textViewMid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainNumber1|R.id.mainNumber2|R.id.mainNumber3);
        textViewBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minus1|R.id.minus2|R.id.minus3);

        textViewUp.setText("1"); // Line 29
        textViewMid.setText("0");
        textViewBottom.setText("59");

        btnUp.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDown.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String getString = String.valueOf(textViewMid.getText());
        int current = Integer.parseInt(getString);
        if (v == btnUp) {
            if (current < nEnd) {
                current++;
                textViewUp.setText(String.valueOf(current - 1));
                textViewMid.setText(String.valueOf(current));
                textViewBottom.setText(String.valueOf(current + 1));
            }

        }
        if (v == btnDown) {
            if (current > nStart) {
                current--;
                textViewUp.setText(String.valueOf(current - 1));
                textViewMid.setText(String.valueOf(current));
                textViewBottom.setText(String.valueOf(current + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonUp1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/up_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plus1"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="plus"
            android:textColor="#cc8400"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/topBar1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainNumber1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Main"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/lowerBar1"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minus1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="minus"
            android:textColor="#cc8400"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDown1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/down_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

<!-- start center numberpicker -->

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonUp2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/up_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plus2"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="plus"
            android:textColor="#cc8400"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/topBar2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainNumber2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Main"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/lowerBar2"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minus2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="minus"
            android:textColor="#cc8400"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDown2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/down_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- start right numberpicker -->

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonUp3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/up_btn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plus3"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="plus"
            android:textColor="#cc8400"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/topBar3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mainNumber3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Main"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/lowerBar3"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minus3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="minus"
            android:textColor="#cc8400"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDown3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/down_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.azurespot.numbpicksample/com.azurespot.numbpicksample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.azurespot.numbpicksample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Comment: WHat is line no 29????

Comment: why this `|` in `btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp1|R.id.buttonUp2|R.id.buttonUp3);`

Comment: `textViewUp.setText("1");` may be number 29 I guess.

Comment: @Lal, line #29 is `textViewUp.setText("1");`. @Raghunandan the pipe is used so I can reference all 3 IDs at once, so I don't have to write code for all of them. Is that allowed? Android Studio shows no compile errors for that.

Comment: Sorry..I dont think so...That may be the reason for your error..Initialise them separately...

Comment: @NoniA. there is no Pipeline Rules over here.so remove it.

Comment: @NoniA. don't do that. `textViewUp` is null

Comment: Ah okay... I will try that and let you know if it helps.

Comment: I don't think this syntax is possible: `btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp1|R.id.buttonUp2|R.id.buttonUp3);` It's only for DEMO purposes, you have to do as many findViewById as many are the controls. And every "multiple findViewById", has to be split into "single findViewById"

Comment: Thanks everyone, trying to change this now. But do you know, can I assign them all similar views the same variable name? For instance can `textViewUp` be assigned to `R.id.plus1` and the other plus2 and plus 3 too? Or do they all have to have a unique variable name?

Comment: I don't understand why my question was down-voted. I am asking a legitimate Android question and needed help (which I am getting). What if someone else makes this mistake? Whoever down voted, please explain. thank you.

Comment: You can find the id of every view in your R.java file. And thats auto generated(can't be changed) and unique. The syntax allows you to use OR. Because the result will be an int. But there might be no view with the id of the result                R.id.buttonUp1|R.id.buttonUp2|R.id.buttonUp3. Thats the reason for the NPE. And +1 for you..

Comment: Yes that can be done but of no use i think,..Because after you initialise 3 times with 3 values,the last value only be visible..

Comment: Thanks @Sripath and Lal :) I'm still new with rearranging code in Android, so trying to see how I can avoided repeating code where possible. But I see now, with the IDs it looks like you must reference them uniquely. I think I saw a pipe used to separate layout variables in an XML file once (which worked), so that's where I got the idea. But I see this is a very different thing. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Really appreciating you for your tries and thinking in a different way(this will lead you to learn many things). Keep trying..

Comment: @NoniA. : That character isn't 'pipe'. In Java it is a bitwise-OR. Everything in the `R.java` class is an int therefore it is legal to use bitwise-OR with things like `R.id.xyz` etc when using `findViewById(...)`. As for repeating code, this is sometimes necessary in all programming - it's what's called boiler-plate coding. If you want 3 buttons (for example) you must declare 3 instances and call `findViewById(...)` for each of them.

Comment: Awe, thanks Sripath, that is nice of you to support with that. @Lal, yeah sure, create an answer and then I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use `|` to separate layout variables while initialising..

So replace this

```
btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp1|R.id.buttonUp2|R.id.buttonUp3);
```

as

```
 btnUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp1);
```

Similarly do it for others also..

Answer (score 1):

You can find the id of every view in your R.java file. And thats auto generated(can't be changed) and unique. The syntax allows you to use OR. Because the result will be an int. But there might be no view with the id of the result R.id.buttonUp1|R.id.buttonUp2|R.id.buttonUp3. Thats the reason for the NPE

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button buttonUp1;
    Button buttonUp2;
    Button buttonUp3;
    Button buttonDown1;
    Button buttonDown2;
    Button buttonDown3;
    TextView mainNumber1;
    TextView mainNumber2;
    TextView mainNumber3;
    TextView plus1;
    TextView plus2;
    TextView plus3;
    TextView minus1;
    TextView minus2;
    TextView minus3;


    int nStart = 0;
    int nEnd = 59;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonUp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp1);
        buttonUp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp2);
        buttonUp3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUp3);
        buttonDown1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDown1);
        buttonDown2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDown2);
        buttonDown3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDown3);


        // All the numbers
        mainNumber1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainNumber1);
        mainNumber2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainNumber2);
        mainNumber3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainNumber3);
        plus1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plus1);
        plus2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plus2);
        plus3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.plus3);
        minus1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minus1);
        minus2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minus2);
        minus3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minus3);


        plus1.setText("1");
        plus2.setText("1");
        plus3.setText("1");
        minus1.setText("59");
        minus2.setText("59");
        minus3.setText("59");
        mainNumber1.setText("0");
        mainNumber2.setText("0");
        mainNumber3.setText("0");

        buttonUp1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUp2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUp3.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonDown1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonDown2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonDown3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonUp1 :
                int upp1 = Integer.parseInt(plus1.getText().toString());
                int upm1 = Integer.parseInt(mainNumber1.getText().toString());
                int upd1 = Integer.parseInt(minus1.getText().toString());
                if (upm1 < nEnd) {
                    upm1++;
                    plus1.setText(String.valueOf(upp1 + 1));
                    mainNumber1.setText(String.valueOf(upm1));
                    minus1.setText(String.valueOf(upd1 - 1));
                }
            break;
            case R.id.buttonUp2 :
                int upp2 = Integer.parseInt(plus2.getText().toString());
                int upm2 = Integer.parseInt(mainNumber2.getText().toString());
                int upd2 = Integer.parseInt(minus2.getText().toString());
                if (upm2 < nEnd) {
                    upm2++;
                    plus2.setText(String.valueOf(upp2 + 1));
                    mainNumber2.setText(String.valueOf(upm2));
                    minus2.setText(String.valueOf(upd2 - 1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonUp3 :
                int upp3 = Integer.parseInt(plus3.getText().toString());
                int upm3 = Integer.parseInt(mainNumber3.getText().toString());
                int upd3 = Integer.parseInt(minus3.getText().toString());
                if (upm3 < nEnd) {
                    upm3++;
                    plus3.setText(String.valueOf(upp3 + 1));
                    mainNumber3.setText(String.valueOf(upm3));
                    minus3.setText(String.valueOf(upd3 - 1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDown1 :
                int downp1 = Integer.parseInt(plus1.getText().toString());
                int downm1 = Integer.parseInt(mainNumber1.getText().toString());
                int downd1 = Integer.parseInt(minus1.getText().toString());
                if (downm1 > nStart) {
                    downm1--;
                    plus1.setText(String.valueOf(downp1 - 1));
                    mainNumber1.setText(String.valueOf(downm1));
                    minus1.setText(String.valueOf(downd1 + 1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDown2 :
                int downp2 = Integer.parseInt(plus2.getText().toString());
                int downm2 = Integer.parseInt(mainNumber2.getText().toString());
                int downd2 = Integer.parseInt(minus2.getText().toString());
                if (downm2 > nStart) {
                    downm2--;
                    plus2.setText(String.valueOf(downp2 - 1));
                    mainNumber2.setText(String.valueOf(downm2));
                    minus2.setText(String.valueOf(downd2 + 1));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDown3 :
                int downp3 = Integer.parseInt(plus3.getText().toString());
                int downm3 = Integer.parseInt(mainNumber3.getText().toString());
                int downd3 = Integer.parseInt(minus3.getText().toString());
                if (downm3 > nStart) {
                    downm3--;
                    plus3.setText(String.valueOf(downp3 - 1));
                    mainNumber3.setText(String.valueOf(downm3));
                    minus3.setText(String.valueOf(downd3 + 1));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```